# Apache - How to map a domain to specific path of another domain on the same host?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a Wordpress website having a domain for example: `example.com` and there're a few pages like `example.com/shop` , `example.com/products/sample-product` which I want to be viewed via `myshopexampledotcom` , `myshopexampledotcom/products/sample-product` respectively. I know writing a simple 301 redirect will do the job but I don't want to create a new Wordpress site for `myshopexampledotcom` instead I would like to simply map specific pages from `example.com` to `myshopexampledotcom`. Is it possible via writing something inside a `VirtualHost`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i misunderstood the question but ProxyPass will do the thing. If you want to map example.com/shop to myshopexample.com you need to add below line in your example.com virtualhost configuration.

```
ProxyPass /shop http://myshopexample.com/
ProxyPassReverse /shop http://myshopexample.com/
```

For this you need to enable mod_proxy module in your apache configuration.
Read more for reverse proxy guide.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html